# Serialize Generic Object in Xml

Tags: c#, xml

I used the following class for serialization

```
public abstract class XmlSeralizerHelper
    {
        public abstract string FileName { get; set; }

        public static T Load<T>() where T : XmlSeralizerHelper, new()
        {
            T result = new T();
            result = XmlFile.Load<T>(result.FileName) ?? result;
            return result;
        }
      
        public void Save()
        {
            XmlFile.Save(FileName, this);
        }
    }

    public static class XmlFile
    {
        public static void Save<T>(string fileName, T @object)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, @object);
            writer.Close();
        }

        public static T Load<T>(string fileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I use the save method I get an error

> InvalidOperationException: The type WpfApp19.DemoSetting was not
> expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types
> that are not known statically.

Comment: Do you have an example xml? What is confusing about the error message?

Comment: The need of `XmlInclude` suggests that you want to serialize a property or collection with a non-sealed base type but the standard `XmlSerializer` does not support that without specifying the possible derived types by the `XmlInclude` attribute. This is intended because `XmlSerializer` does not want to be real a polymorphic serializer due to security reasons.  You can try [my XML serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#xml-serialization) to overcome this issue. See an online example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2dfrx).